# Create a table that return counts of each value for multiple variables

Tags: r, dataframe, count, frequency

This is my dataframe

```
# Load libraries
library(data.table)
library(expss)
library(sjlabelled) # to call function as_label()

# Create dataframe
a <- data.table("b1" = c(1, 2, 2, 2),  
                "b2" = c(1, 2, 1, 1),
                "b3" = c(1, 1, 1, 1))

# Set value label
val_lab(a) = num_lab("
            1 Yes
            2 No    
")
a = as_label(a)
```

and it looks like this:

```
> a
    b1  b2  b3
1: Yes Yes Yes
2:  No  No Yes
3:  No Yes Yes
4:  No Yes Yes
```

I want to create a dataset that return the total occurrence counts of each value and it should look like the following:

```
  Category  b1  b2  b3
1:  Yes     1   3   4
2:  No      3   1   0
```

This might work in a similar way as the `tabout` command in Stata. Also, it would be great to return percentage like this

```
  Category  b1   b2   b3
1:  Yes    25   75   100
2:  No     75   25   0
3:  sum    100  100  100
```

Comment: Are the 2 "Yes" for `b1` a typo? Should that be 1?

Comment: I am very positive about Stata but the mention of `tabout` here is just a distraction. Almost all the people able and willing to answer this question will never have heard of it or used it.

Comment: I've removed the Stata tag for the opposite reason, that Stata people won't be especially interested in this question unless they also use R.

Comment: Thank you Nick for your suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to use the `janitor` package after doing some transformations with tidyverse packages:

```
library(janitor)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

counts <- a %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), values_to = "Category") %>% 
  mutate(Category = c("Yes", "No")[Category]) %>% 
  tabyl(Category, name)
```

**Output**

```
 Category b1 b2 b3
       No  3  1  0
      Yes  1  3  4
```

---

As for the percentages you can use the `janitor` `adorn` functions:

```
counts %>% 
  adorn_percentages(denominator = "col") %>% 
  adorn_totals("row") %>% 
  adorn_pct_formatting()
```

Note, see the `?adorn_pct_formatting` for additional formatting options.

**Output**

```
 Category     b1     b2     b3
       No  75.0%  25.0%   0.0%
      Yes  25.0%  75.0% 100.0%
    Total 100.0% 100.0% 100.0%
```

Comment: When I use tabyl(), the variable labels of b1,b2,b3 disappears, I wonder whether there is a way to keep them. Also, is there any chances to draw a stacked bar graph having each variable as a bar, or I have to convert to long dataset? Thank you

Comment: @James_greyyy What I have posted is the exact output I get from using `tabyl`, which should include the variable labels. As for plotting, it depends somewhat. If you are using `ggplot2` to plot then yes you will have to convert to long format.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pivots and simple aggregations with tidyverse, although I would also agree with @LMc that `janitor` is a great package for tabular summaries.

```
library(tidyverse)

a |> 
  pivot_longer(everything()) |> 
  group_by(name, value) |> 
  summarise(n = n()) |> 
  mutate(p = n / sum(n)) |> 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = value, names_from = name, values_from = n, values_fill = 0)

# A tibble: 2 × 4
  value    b1    b2    b3
  <chr> <int> <int> <int>
1 No        3     1     0
2 Yes       1     3     4
```

Or with `values_from = p` instead:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  value    b1    b2    b3
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 No     0.75  0.25     0
2 Yes    0.25  0.75     1
```